# div background-image goes blank on hover in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I have an element that should change `background-image` when someone hovers over it. 
However, the background images are SVGs as `data-uri`s.

It works perfectly on Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera) and works well on IE.

However, on Firefox, whenever I hover, the image simply goes blank. When I try and fiddle with it by inspecting the element and maybe changing the color or some other unrelated the style, the image magically appears.

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

This is my CSS:

```
.info .comment{
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg"%20fill%3D"%23D9D9D9"%20width%3D"25px"%20height%3D"25px">%0D%0A%20<path%20d%3D"M11.5%201C5.159441000000001%201%200%205.54683583%200%2011.1341066C0%2013.8432911%201.2135882000000038%2016.305879%203.1855000000000047%2018.1266402C3.3234999999999957%2018.2536543%203.4046764999999937%2018.4293122%203.4046764999999937%2018.6164553L3.4046764999999937%2024.1449483C3.2423234999999977%2024.7442118%203.9045882000000063%2025.2259197%204.426147099999994%2024.8887917L8.889499999999998%2021.2411889C9.039676%2021.118904%209.233823999999998%2021.0702603%209.425264999999996%2021.1006627C10.098353000000003%2021.210111%2010.791735000000003%2021.2682132%2011.5%2021.2682132C17.841234999999998%2021.2682132%2023%2016.722053%2023%2011.1341066C23%205.54683583%2017.841234999999998%201%2011.5%201"%2F>%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A<%2Fsvg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info:hover .comment, .info:visited .comment{
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg"%20fill%3D"%23CCCCCC"%20width%3D"25px"%20height%3D"25px">%0D%0A%20<path%20d%3D"M11.5%201C5.159441000000001%201%200%205.54683583%200%2011.1341066C0%2013.8432911%201.2135882000000038%2016.305879%203.1855000000000047%2018.1266402C3.3234999999999957%2018.2536543%203.4046764999999937%2018.4293122%203.4046764999999937%2018.6164553L3.4046764999999937%2024.1449483C3.2423234999999977%2024.7442118%203.9045882000000063%2025.2259197%204.426147099999994%2024.8887917L8.889499999999998%2021.2411889C9.039676%2021.118904%209.233823999999998%2021.0702603%209.425264999999996%2021.1006627C10.098353000000003%2021.210111%2010.791735000000003%2021.2682132%2011.5%2021.2682132C17.841234999999998%2021.2682132%2023%2016.722053%2023%2011.1341066C23%205.54683583%2017.841234999999998%201%2011.5%201"%2F>%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A<%2Fsvg>');
}

.info:hover {
color:#CCCCCC
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<a class="info" href="#">
            <div class="comment" role="img"></div>
            500
            </a>
```

Comment: I threw your code into a quick html file (and a jsfiddle), and everything seemed to work fine in Firefox. Does the same thing happen in a private window? Or after you clear the cache?

Comment: works for me, [check my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/tcynrd62/)

Comment: @wmeade You're right do work. However I just added the :visited state and then it breaks. I found the cause for it to go blank. Just need to know why

Comment: @leftside see the comment above also, see http://jsfiddle.net/tcynrd62/2/ it breaks in firefox. don't know why...

Comment: if you're asking about the `:visited` state, it might be good to update the question.

Comment: @leftside but it goes blank when I hover over the element?

Comment: You mentioned in your first comment (to wmeade) that it does work on `:hover` - unless I'm reading that incorrectly. If it also doesn't work on `:visited`, we should know that as well. `:hover` works fine on Firefox for me.

Comment: Only colours can be used to style visited links: http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy

Comment: or from the source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3Avisited_selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because order matters when using any `pseudo-class`. Firefox honors the [CSS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) on `:visited` whereas webkit based browsers will allow since they are more loose when it comes to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes).

Example in codepen:

http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/GpVXMN

Same example in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/98assuba/1/

You need to make sure you use the pseudo-class `:link` when using `:visited`.

Since the spec dictates that `:link` must come before `:visited`. So since you are adding it to the same CSS rule as your `:hover`, then you must add it to the default state of the `.info .comment` rule.

So add the line `.info:link .comment` to the same CSS rule as `.info .comment`

And move `.info:visited .comment` before `.info:hover .comment`

```
.info:link .comment, /* add this line */
.info .comment{
     background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg"%20fill%3D"%23D9D9D9"%20width%3D"25px"%20height%3D"25px">%0D%0A%20<path%20d%3D"M11.5%201C5.159441000000001%201%200%205.54683583%200%2011.1341066C0%2013.8432911%201.2135882000000038%2016.305879%203.1855000000000047%2018.1266402C3.3234999999999957%2018.2536543%203.4046764999999937%2018.4293122%203.4046764999999937%2018.6164553L3.4046764999999937%2024.1449483C3.2423234999999977%2024.7442118%203.9045882000000063%2025.2259197%204.426147099999994%2024.8887917L8.889499999999998%2021.2411889C9.039676%2021.118904%209.233823999999998%2021.0702603%209.425264999999996%2021.1006627C10.098353000000003%2021.210111%2010.791735000000003%2021.2682132%2011.5%2021.2682132C17.841234999999998%2021.2682132%2023%2016.722053%2023%2011.1341066C23%205.54683583%2017.841234999999998%201%2011.5%201"%2F>%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A<%2Fsvg>');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     color: #D9D9D9;
     display: inline-block;
}

.info:visited .comment, /* add this before :hover */
.info:hover .comment{
     background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg"%20fill%3D"%23CCCCCC"%20width%3D"25px"%20height%3D"25px">%0D%0A%20<path%20d%3D"M11.5%201C5.159441000000001%201%200%205.54683583%200%2011.1341066C0%2013.8432911%201.2135882000000038%2016.305879%203.1855000000000047%2018.1266402C3.3234999999999957%2018.2536543%203.4046764999999937%2018.4293122%203.4046764999999937%2018.6164553L3.4046764999999937%2024.1449483C3.2423234999999977%2024.7442118%203.9045882000000063%2025.2259197%204.426147099999994%2024.8887917L8.889499999999998%2021.2411889C9.039676%2021.118904%209.233823999999998%2021.0702603%209.425264999999996%2021.1006627C10.098353000000003%2021.210111%2010.791735000000003%2021.2682132%2011.5%2021.2682132C17.841234999999998%2021.2682132%2023%2016.722053%2023%2011.1341066C23%205.54683583%2017.841234999999998%201%2011.5%201"%2F>%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A<%2Fsvg>');
}

.info:hover {
     color:#CCCCCC
}
```

Taken from the Firefox MDN CSS reference docs for `:visited`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

> The :visited CSS pseudo-class lets you select only links that have been visited. This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes, that is :link, :hover, and :active, appearing in subsequent rules. In order to style appropriately links, you need to put the :visited rule after the :link rule but before the other ones, defined in the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

And the W3C Spec for psuedo-class `:visited`

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes

So remember to always place the pseudo-class's in a specific order (even if on a different rule for the same element):

> LVHA order: :link  —  :visited  —  :hover  —  :active

In other words you could remember the order like this:

**L**ord **V**ader's **H**andle formerly **A**nakin

Once you use the proper order for pseudo-classes, the browser will render properly consistently.